# CVS repository commit file

Tags: cvs

I'm getting errors when I try to commit a file with CVS (note that I'm a beginner).

FYI: I'm doing this locally on my terminal...not with Eclipse.

Steps I've taken so far.

1. created a repository for cvs.
2. imported my module into the repository successfully.
3. successfully did a checkout on my module and I see the revision copy in the folder (`~testing.cpp`)
4. I then changed the file testing.cpp and made some updates.
5. I then went to commit the file testing.cpp

Command line:

```
cvs commit testing.cpp
```

I get this error message:

> cannot open CVS/Entries for reading: No such file or directory cvs
>   commit: nothing known about `testing.cpp'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You’re using CVS because you have to and not because you want to, right? … right?

Comment: Please use a modern version control system like git, mercurial or subversion.

Comment: Okay, so in the folder where you checked out `testing.cpp`, is there a `CVS` folder?  What are the permissions on `CVS/Entries`?  Does the file even exist?  Does it contain any reference to `testing.cpp`?  Are you sure you haven't changed any part of the filename from lowercase to uppercase?  That error message is telling you something important.

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 root             staff  141 Feb 27 21:06 Entries

Comment: so.....I'm guessing that I have to make it rwx????

Comment: I Figured it out.....I was committing the file from within the WRONG folder!!!  Thank you for your help paddy!

Comment: Did you run `cvs commit testing.cpp` from the actual directory where `testing.cpp` is located?

Comment: Oh, yeah jinx.  Just got your comment after writing mine.

Comment: yep, that was the problem. thank you!